# C# Webform in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, datagridview

I really a very new at this:
I have a very simple C# webform that is linked to a SQL backend.
The object is to track entrances/exits etc into a small theatre.
So, my users will use the text entry fields to enter details which also show up on the datagridview at the bottom of the form. All works well with no problems etc.
However, the days list needs to be printed (not a problem) and then closed. I want the form to be blank on next opening with the datagridview clear to accept new entries i.e. next available space (record) in the database.
I have tried a button configured with:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theatreTblDataGridView.DataSource = null;
        theatreTblDataGridView.Refresh();
```

This does clear the datagridview but new entries can be made via the text boxes and do get stored to the DB but datagridview no longer populates. If I close the form and reopen it shows all of the records created..
In Access I could achieve this by making the form property = Data Entry.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You need to share the code which stores the data from textbox to database? Does that code also reloads data from database and refreshes the grid?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am simply using a binding source and have not really written any code (this is all new to me). Could you please elaborate as to how I could go about what you say? I have created a 'DailyView' in SQL server. When I ran this it does give the top line entry in the DataGridView as I need. If I change the Binding Source to this I still cannot blank the form on opening to leave the next record available for population and the data  grid stays blank The SQL query is: create view DailyView as select * from TheatreTbl where CAST(CREATED as date) = CAST(getdate() as date)